# TableView scrollToIndex doesn't show entire row

Tags: titanium, tableview, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

- Application Type: mobile
- Titanium SDK: 3.1.1.GA
- Platform & Version: iOS 6.1
- Device: iOS Simulator
- Host Operating System: OSX 10.8.3
- Titanium Studio: 3.1.1.201306112235

I'm using the scrollToIndex method to scroll a tableView to display an entire row in view. This works fine for all rows except the last one. Right before I call scrollToIndex I'm updating a row with a new one that has a greater height. The scrollToIndex function does scroll to the last row in this case, but it only shows the top portion of it, and not the entire row. How do I get scrollToIndex to show the entire row?

Answer (score 0):

*scrollToIndex* function have an optional parameter, *animation*. Look [here!!](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TableView-method-scrollToIndex).

On iOS, you can specify *TableViewAnimationProperties* object to control the position that the selected row is scrolled to, and whether scrolling is animated.You can look at following links for more information

1.[Table View Animation Properties](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/TableViewAnimationProperties)

2.[Table View Scroll Position](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.iPhone.TableViewScrollPosition)

Hope it helped you.